# DITA OT Preprocessing

Tags: dita, dita-ot

I started working on DITA OT. I had gone through its process of transforming Topics into XHTML.

While reading I understood that it uses two processes

1. Preprocess
2. Transform

Then I started looking into preprocessing coding part in Java. Understood the process but not able to understand the flow specifically how it creates “job.xml” in the temp directory.

can anyone help me understand this part in the aspect of programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing structure is very well explained in the [docs](https://www.dita-ot.org/3.2/reference/architecture.html). You can change various aspects of the processing by using extension points and overriding mechanisms.